# Inconsistent errors saving in Grails 2.1.1

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm deploying a Grails 2.1.1 app to several RedHat 64 Linux servers in the AWS environment.  the app server is Tomcat 7, database is MySQL 5.1.69. 
  On most servers the deployment was uneventful.  On one final deployment there is one save operation that is failing almost always.  this is using the same data as in the servers where the operation is working.

I've deployed from an automated Jenkins build to two locations, with the only difference being the deployment destination.  Same Config.groovy, same Datasource.groovy. 
On one server, I'm seeing the messages below which end in a transaction rolling back., but no usable error message.

When logging all  hibernate messages, the logs  never show an INSERT statement on the server that is failing where there is an insert message on the server that works.

the transaction manager messages are below:

> 2014-04-10 17:32:08,969 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6] TRACE
>   spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@1b05c20:
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.ValidationEvent[source=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore@66926b7e]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,969 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6] TRACE
>   support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in Root
>   WebApplicationContext:
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.ValidationEvent[source=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore@66926b7e]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,969 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6] TRACE
>   support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Retrieved value
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@540b17a] for key
>   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6a71b732] bound to thread
>   [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,971 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]
>   DEBUG beans.BeanUtils  - No property editor [java.lang.StringEditor]
>   found for type java.lang.String according to 'Editor' suffix
>   convention  2014-04-10 17:32:08,972 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6] TRACE
>   support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Retrieved value
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@540b17a] for key
>   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6a71b732] bound to thread
>   [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,972 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]
>   TRACE support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Retrieved value
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@540b17a] for key
>   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6a71b732] bound to thread
>   [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,972 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]
>   TRACE support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Retrieved value
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@540b17a] for key
>   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6a71b732] bound to thread
>   [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]  2014-04-10 17:32:08,977 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-6]
>   TRACE interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  - Completing transaction for
>   [com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.XXXFormService.addSegmentWithName] after
>   exception: java.lang.Exception: Could not save new group

Are there libraries deep within Grails that can cause issues?